# Is it possible to do classification without converting the data into numeric values?

Tags: python, classification, knn

I am trying to understand the work of KNN (k-nearest neighbors) for the classification of the Iris dataset. As I understood, when I need to do classification, I have to prepare my data into numerical values. Based on the below code that I followed, it did not change them into numerical values. Is it correct? When do I need to change them into numerical values, and when not? This is because, based on the below code, he achieved 0.97 precision. May I get clarification, please?

```
# import libraries 
import pandas as pd # Import Pandas for data manipulation using dataframes
import numpy as np # Import Numpy for data statistical analysis 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # Import matplotlib for data visualisation
import seaborn as sns

# dataframes creation for both training and testing datasets 
iris_df = pd.read_csv('iris.csv')

# Let's drop the ID and Species (target label) columns
X = iris_df.drop(['Species'],axis=1)
X

y = iris_df['Species']
y

# Import train_test_split from scikit library
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.35)

# Fitting K-NN to the Training set
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix

classifier = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = 5, metric = 'minkowski', p = 2)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_predict = classifier.predict(X_test)
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_predict)
sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True, fmt="d")

print(classification_report(y_test, y_predict))
```